# Does ASP allow you to escape from script tags like PHP?

Tags: php, asp-classic

Can you escape in and out of ASP tags like how PHP can exit out of parsing mode?  For instance, in PHP, you can exit in the middle of a code block, which is useful if you want to show long chunks of HTML code.

```
<?php if ($expression == true) { ?>

    <h1>This will show if the expression is true.</h1>
    <p>I can put lots of HTML code here.</p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, ASP can be written along with HTML, but it is better to avoid

Comment: I agree with you FirmView, but to be fair, can you completely avoid combining "script code" with HTML? Even functions often have to output data and at least some minimal HTML.

Comment: @podiluska is correct. And so is Firmview. You can, but I think it's better to use something that separates the layers of design and functionality better. ASP.NET is a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

```
 <% if (expression) then %>
     <h1>This will show if the expression is true.</h1>  
     <p>I can put lots of HTML code here.</p>  
 <% end if %>
```

The kind of spaghetti like mess that this could create was one of the major flaws in classic ASP, unless one made strenuous efforts to keep ones code manageable.

I'm not sure why you'd want to use classic ASP though. (Or php, for that matter)

Comment: Great, this worked.  I had to add "then" after the expression, though:

`<% if (expression) then %>`

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote any :-)